# ElasticSearch - Slop use case

Tags: elasticsearch, proximity

I'm pretty new in Elastic Search, and I'm trying to use slop attribute to solve a problem.

**The problem :**

I have a multi_match query, and one of the field is full of codes like :

*Example 1* : "AE 102 BR, V 415 A, K45863"

*Example 2 :* "AE 100 BR, AE 101 BR, AE 103 BR, AE 104 BR"

The problem is that sometimes the Example 2 will be choosen for the query "AE 102 BR", because ES find multiple times "AE" and "BR".

The solution I want is boost the "close matching", by this I mean if I have 1 "3 consecutives words" match, it has to be always more relevant than 4 "2 consecutives words" match.

**What I've try :**

```
"multi_match": { 
                "fields": [ "field1^10", "field2^3", 
                "field3^3", "**field_code**^3", "global_compatibilities^1" ] 
                , "query": "AE 102 BR",
                "slop":  1
            }
```

but it doesn't work (the "slop" doesn't change anything to the score).

Can someone explains me better how to use slop in my case ?